# WP8: Debug not attached bugs

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, directx, release, sharpdx

I'm writing games using C# and SharpDX (WP8).

There are many bugs when debugger is not attached (textures are cut, incorrect colors
in pixel shader).

But when debugger is attached, everything works fine.

what is the difference between attached and detached debugger?
How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a little code example replicating the problem? Also do you load your resources as Async, and wait for them to be properly loaded before to start rendering?

Answer (score 0):

All your code runs faster without the debugger attached (particularly if you're debugging on the phone).

You question strongly indicates that you've got race-condition bugs in your code.

Try a Release (optimised) build, try the Emulator debugger, or use logging to find these issues.

Comment: It is working alright in the Emulator (with attached debug, and without atteched debugger). The bug is reproducing on devices only.

Comment: I've found strange semi-solution: there should be pitch (size of two pixels) before pixel data. For example, texture format is bgra4444, size is 2, 2 * 2 = 4, I should allocated size of data + 4 bytes and put data with offset 4 bytes. For 32bit textures this value is 8 bytes. I thinks this is sharpdx @feature@